# getCurrentLocationInBackground Parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform, geolocation, geopoints

I'm trying to develop application that uses GPS locations for services. Each service should has a location (GeoPoint). I'm trying to get my current location and save it to parse database. I tried to use getCurrentLocationInBackground but unfortunately there is not guide on how to use this. I used the below code but unfortunately it't not working. Please help!

```
void getLocation() {


        // ParseGeoPoint location = null;
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_LOW);
        criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
        criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
        criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);

        ParseGeoPoint.getCurrentLocationInBackground(20000, criteria, new LocationCallback() {
          @Override
          public void done(ParseGeoPoint geoPoint, ParseException e) {

            if (e == null) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), geoPoint.getLatitude()+"", 50000).show();


            } else {
              // handle your error
              e.printStackTrace();
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error", 50000).show();
            }
          }
        });


}
```

Comment: Trying the same code in my app. It may take time from 2 min for 10 min for fetching location... Too slow, i think

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by adding the following dependency in build.grade:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0'
}
```

I also had to **remove** all `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` and  `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permissions from AndroidManifest.xml, which seems very strange.

The way you have defined the Criteria is correct, and also necessary.

This is a really nice feature in the Parse.com API but I wish they would provide some documentation. As is, I don't really trust it... I'm just using it as a quick and dirty solution until I have time to implement Google Play Services properly.

Comment: no matter what i do i always get fetch timout. i removed the 2 permissions from the manifest and have the latest googe play services imported with gradle, any ideas?