# Android ParseGeoPoint.getCurrentLocationInBackground is null

Tags: android, parse-platform

Here is my code:

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
ParseGeoPoint.getCurrentLocationInBackground(10000, criteria,new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseGeoPoint parseGeoPoint, ParseException e) {

            if (parseGeoPoint != null) {
                Double lat = parseGeoPoint.getLatitude();
                Double longi = parseGeoPoint.getLongitude();
                LatLng myLatLng = new LatLng(lat, longi);
                mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myLatLng, 13));
            } else {
                Log.wtf(TAG, "PARSEGEOPOINT WAS NULL FML!");
            }
        }
    });
```

I am getting the FML log statement everytime, I don't have the slightest idea what I am missing or doing wrong.

Comment: Print `e.getMessage()` to the log and post the error.

Comment: The error was "location fetch timed out." as you can see, I have set a pretty high timeout already, but I will try increasing it.

Comment: And, tried increasing the timeout (by a factor of 10) didn't work.

Comment: That's still only one second, that is not very long to wait for a location fix.

Comment: I changed it to 100,000. Still did not work.

Comment: Well this could be due to multiple factors. Firstly, try changing the accuracy to low instead of fine

Comment: This worked for me:

[Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290728/getcurrentlocationinbackground-parse-com)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same behavior.  I discovered that I hadn't added permissions to my manifest.  Try adding to your AndroidManifest.xml:  (+ Fine if you need it)

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>